# Cannot find module './packager/babelRegisterOnly'

Tags: react-native

This error probably has to do with package manager and happens when I run `react-native start`

Full Error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './packager/babelRegisterOnly'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/amirsharif/mobile-rappad/node_modules/react-native/cli.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled react native with NPM then ran `npm install react-native` again and it worked. I cleared out everything in the node_modules folder.

Comment: Running into same issue, so you deleted the node_modules for the project. Then uninstalled react-native, re-installed and ran `npm install react-native`?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall react-native fitst, then re-install it.  It's work to me.